# Navigating between ViewControllers with UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uialertview, pushviewcontroller

I'm trying to change view controllers based on a user's selection in a `UIAlertView`. I'm new to objective c and am having some trouble.

When the user presses "I'm done", i want the app to navigate back to the previous view controller. When the user presses "Scoreboard", i want the app to navigate to the next view controller.

```
UIAlertView *jigsawCompleteAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]   //show alert box with option to play or exit
                                  initWithTitle: @"Congratulations!" 
                                  message:completedMessage 
                                  delegate:self 
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"I'm done" 
                                  otherButtonTitles:@"Play again", @"Scoreboard",nil];
            [jigsawCompleteAlert show];

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        NSLog(@"Cancel Tapped.");
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    }
    else if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        NSLog(@"GO tapped.");
        startDate = [NSDate date];
        // Create the stop watch timer that fires every 10 ms
        stopWatchTimer = [NSTimer 
                          scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/10.0
                          target:self
                          selector:@selector(updateTimer)
                          userInfo:nil
                          repeats:YES];
    } else if (buttonIndex == 2) {
        NSLog(@"Scoreboard tapped.");
    }

}
```

The popView part is working, and the app navigates back one view controller. I don't know how to get the app to move forward one view controller. I know it's something to do with `pushViewController` but i've only seen quite old and contradictory articles detailing how to do this.

I'd appreciate some help with this, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create new UIViewController and then push it to stack, something like this:

```
else if (buttonIndex == 2) {
    NSLog(@"Scoreboard tapped.");
    MoreDetailViewController *ctrl = [[MoreDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MoreDetailViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:ctrl animated:YES];
}
```

If you are using StoryBoard then provide identifier for your UIViewController in storyboard file (Attribute Inspector).
[image]

Put this code into handler:

```
MoreDetailViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MoreDetailViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to import the view controller first? I'm using ARC so the code i've used is `UIViewController *ctrl = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AssignmentViewController3" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:ctrl animated:YES];`. I currently have no segue between viewcontroller2 and viewcontroller3 so am getting the "scene unreachable" warning. The files are named AssignmentViewController3.h and AssignmentViewController3.m but i'm not sure if that means AssignmentViewController3 is the NIB name. Thanks again

Comment: Yes. add line #import "AssignmentViewController3.h". And instead UIViewController type AssignmentViewController3

Comment: I'm getting a SIGABRT error - `Could not load NIB in bundle.....with name AssignmentViewController3`. The code i'm now using is `AssignmentViewController3 *ctrl = [[AssignmentViewController3 alloc] initWithNibName:@"AssignmentViewController3" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:ctrl animated:YES];`. I'm not sure if this is happening because i've never explicitly set the NIB name as i don't know how?

Comment: Maybe I should have mentioned that i'm using a storyboard. Does that have any effect on what code i should be using?

Comment: That's great beryllium, thanks. I probably should have mentioned earlier that i was using a Storyboard. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Simply call the following:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewControllerToPush animated:YES];
```

If you don't have a view controller set up, you'll need to create one programmatically or link one up through Interface Builder using a IBOutlet in your header file.